# Scala won't run in IntelliJ

Tags: java, linux, scala, intellij-idea, ubuntu-18.04

When I try to run any scala code in intillij, I get the following error:

> Information:07/07/18 10:20 - Compilation completed with 1 error and 1 warning in 3 s 617 ms
>       Error:scalac: Error: org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.ServerException
>       java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at sbt.internal.inc.RawCompiler.getReporter$1(RawCompiler.scala:50)
>           at sbt.internal.inc.RawCompiler.apply(RawCompiler.scala:71)
>           at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler$.$anonfun$compileSources$6(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:350)
>           at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler$.handleCompilationError$1(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:327)
>           at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler$.$anonfun$compileSources$4(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:346)
>           at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler$.$anonfun$compileSources$4$adapted(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:341)
>           at sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:376)
>           at sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:383)
>           at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler$.$anonfun$compileSources$2(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:341)
>           at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler$.$anonfun$compileSources$2$adapted(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:335)
>           at sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:376)
>           at sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:383)
>           at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler$.compileSources(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:335)
>           at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl$.getOrCompileInterfaceJar(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:128)
>           at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl.$anonfun$getScalac$1(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:49)
>           at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
>           at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl.getScalac(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:47)
>           at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl.createCompiler(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:25)
>           at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CachingFactory.$anonfun$createCompiler$3(CachingFactory.scala:24)
>           at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.Cache.$anonfun$getOrUpdate$2(Cache.scala:20)
>           at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
>           at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.Cache.getOrUpdate(Cache.scala:19)
>           at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CachingFactory.createCompiler(CachingFactory.scala:24)
>           at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.LocalServer.compile(LocalServer.scala:22)
>           at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.make(Main.scala:83)
>           at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.nailMain(Main.scala:26)
>           at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main.nailMain(Main.scala)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at com.martiansoftware.nailgun.NGSession.run(NGSession.java:319)
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.ByteBuffer.clear()Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;
>           at scala.tools.nsc.io.SourceReader.read(SourceReader.scala:61)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.io.SourceReader.read(SourceReader.scala:40)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.io.SourceReader.read(SourceReader.scala:49)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.Global.getSourceFile(Global.scala:395)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.Global.getSourceFile(Global.scala:401)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run$$anonfun$30.apply(Global.scala:1607)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run$$anonfun$30.apply(Global.scala:1607)
>           at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:284)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compile(Global.scala:1607)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.doCompile(Driver.scala:32)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.MainClass.doCompile(Main.scala:23)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.process(Driver.scala:51)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.Main.process(Main.scala)
>           ... 36 more
>       Warning:scalac: error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.ByteBuffer.clear()Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;
>           at scala.tools.nsc.io.SourceReader.read(SourceReader.scala:61)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.io.SourceReader.read(SourceReader.scala:40)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.io.SourceReader.read(SourceReader.scala:49)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.Global.getSourceFile(Global.scala:395)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.Global.getSourceFile(Global.scala:401)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run$$anonfun$30.apply(Global.scala:1607)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run$$anonfun$30.apply(Global.scala:1607)
>           at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:284)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compile(Global.scala:1607)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.doCompile(Driver.scala:32)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.MainClass.doCompile(Main.scala:23)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.process(Driver.scala:51)
>           at scala.tools.nsc.Main.process(Main.scala)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at sbt.internal.inc.RawCompiler.getReporter$1(RawCompiler.scala:50)
>           at sbt.internal.inc.RawCompiler.apply(RawCompiler.scala:71)
>           at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler$.$anonfun$compileSources$6(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:350)
>           at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler$.handleCompilationError$1(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:327)
>           at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler$.$anonfun$compileSources$4(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:346)
>           at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler$.$anonfun$compileSources$4$adapted(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:341)
>           at sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:376)
>           at sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:383)
>           at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler$.$anonfun$compileSources$2(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:341)
>           at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler$.$anonfun$compileSources$2$adapted(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:335)
>           at sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:376)
>           at sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:383)
>           at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler$.compileSources(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:335)
>           at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl$.getOrCompileInterfaceJar(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:128)
>           at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl.$anonfun$getScalac$1(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:49)
>           at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
>           at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl.getScalac(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:47)
>           at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl.createCompiler(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:25)
>           at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CachingFactory.$anonfun$createCompiler$3(CachingFactory.scala:24)
>           at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.Cache.$anonfun$getOrUpdate$2(Cache.scala:20)
>           at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
>           at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.Cache.getOrUpdate(Cache.scala:19)
>           at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CachingFactory.createCompiler(CachingFactory.scala:24)
>           at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.LocalServer.compile(LocalServer.scala:22)
>           at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.make(Main.scala:83)
>           at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.nailMain(Main.scala:26)
>           at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main.nailMain(Main.scala)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at com.martiansoftware.nailgun.NGSession.run(NGSession.java:319)

I am running the latest version of intellij and scala, all in ubuntu 18.

It works however when I run scala in the terminal and type in code.

Comment: we need more info on how you configure java in idea? what is the scala version?      how are you running the code in intellij? source codes? the build.sbt file if exists else scala and java configuration in idea and as much infos as you can

Comment: Install the latest version of java, idea and scala. Used snaps to install idea, and and am running it as src.

Comment: object Hello extends App{
    println("Hello, world!")
}

Comment: did you installed scala plugin in intellij?

Answer (score 1):

most likely you are using java and scala versions that are incompatible. See https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html